# nuxt.js: where is the .js for running nuxt start

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, pm2

nuxt version: 2.4.3

I'm using node process manager (pm2) for my node.js hosting. To run nuxt on development server, you can simply `nuxt` or `npm run dev` but that's not the case if you're using pm2's `ecosystem.config.js` which needs you to specify which file actually runs that.

For example, to run a developement server I have to point to the file that runs it which is `./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js`

But I have no idea which file that run production server or `nuxt start`

Can someone points me which file in `./node_modules/nuxt` or `./node_modules/@nuxt` that perform `nuxt start`?

--edit
This [article](https://medium.com/@vipercodegames/nuxt-deploy-809eda0168fc) covers how you run nuxt start with pm2 but aforementioned file `./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt-start` does not exists on mine. I suspect because we are using different nuxt version

Comment: Does it work when you have pm2 run `./node_modules/nuxt start`?

Comment: no, but I can run 
`node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start` to start production server via console, which leads to another question: how do you pass argument inside ecosystem.config.js?

Comment: tried everything in the ecosystem file documentation for adding args but still no avail

Comment: `pm2 start npm -- start` is how I run it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Js file you are looking for (nuxt > 2.3)

```
node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js
```

When using pm2, I'm doing it this way (ecosystem.yml)

```
apps:
- name: client
  script: node_modules/nuxt-start/bin/nuxt-start.js
  cwd: /root/app/client
  max_memory_restart: "250M" 
  args: "start"
```

Notice that for production in this case I'm using *nuxt-start* dependency to speed up *npm i*.

Comment: Hi, can you explain please, why you are using `max_memory_restart: "250M"` ?

Comment: @logandev You can ignore this line, I copy pasted my production config here, this line was responsible for fighting with a memory leak I had back then. Basically it restarts the nuxt service if it consumes too much memory.

BTW, if I recall correctly, the upcoming Nuxt 3 requires a different config, warning just in case someone from the future sees this answer.